# Make a new list by filtering unwanted rows

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this.

```
cdatalist = {{1., 0.898785, Failed, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 1.31175,1., Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 18.8025, Failed, 0.490235, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 19.6628, 0.990079, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 39.547, Failed, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 39.7503, Failed, 0.482749, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 40.2078, Failed, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 40.6208, 0.980588, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 102.588, Failed, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 102.781, Failed, 0.466214, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 102.826, Failed, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {1., 102.833, Failed, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {15., 0.89985, Failed, Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}, {15., 1.31344, 1., $Failed, 50., 25., "serial"}}
```

at the end, I want to compile a new list by dropping any lines that don't have "Failed" on the third column on each row.

```
datalistfunc[input_] :=
 Module[{cell, cell2, celltable, celllist},
  i = 1;
  celllist = {};
  While[i < Length@cdatalist + 1,
cell = 
Select[cdatalist[[i]][[1 ;; 3]], 
 Head[cdatalist[[i]][[3]]] == Real &];
i = If[i < Length@cdatalist + 1, i + 1, Length@cdatalist + 1];
celllist = AppendTo[celllist, cell2];
Print[cell2]
  ]
]
datalist = datalistfunc[cdata];
```

My list looks like this after filtering.

```
{{},{}}
{{1.,1.31175,1.},{}}
{{},{}}
{{1.,19.6628,0.990079},{}}
{{},{}}
{{},{}}
{{},{}}
{{1.,40.6208,0.980588},{}}
{{},{}}
{{},{}}
{{},{}}
{{},{}}
{{},{}}
{{15.,1.31344,1.},{}}
```

Instead, I want my list to look like this.

```
{{1.,1.31175,1.},
{1.,19.6628,0.990079},  
{1.,40.6208,0.980588},
{15.,1.31344,1.}}
```

Answer (score 4):

This matches your example, but I had to get only the first three elements of each line (you didn't mention it).

```
Select[cdatalist, #[[3]] =!= Failed &][[All, ;; 3]]
```

Or, as per @belisarius suggestion (roughly twice as fast!)

```
Cases[cdatalist, Except[{_, _, Failed, ___}]][[All, 1 ;; 3]]
```

Or, "inspired" by @Gerli:

```
Cases[cdatalist , {a_, b_, c : Except[Failed], ___} :> {a, b, c}]
```

Silly benchmark:

```
Do[Select[cdatalist, #[[3]] =!= Failed &][[All, ;; 3]], {100000}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.981000 *)

(* belisarius *)
Do[Cases[cdatalist, Except[{_, _, Failed, ___}]][[All, 1 ;; 3]], {100000}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.747398 *)

(* Gerli-inspired *)
Do[Cases[cdatalist , {a_, b_, c : Except[Failed], ___} :> {a, b, c}], {100000}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.172714 *)

(* kguler's *)
Do[Pick[#, (#[[-1]] =!= Failed) & /@ #] &@ cdatalist[[All, ;; 3]], {100000}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.415208 *)
```

Comment: Also, `Cases[cdatalist, Except[{_, _, Failed, ___}]][[All, 1 ;; 3]]`

Comment: Oh, nice! Benchmark time!

Comment: Nah, pattern matching is almost always too bad performance-wise

Comment: Well, this time you had your cake and ate it too!

Answer (score 2):

Try [Cases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html).

If you want the third column to be Real:

```
Cases[cdatalist, {_, _, _Real, __}][[All, 1 ;; 3]]
```

or

```
Cases[cdatalist[[All, 1 ;; 3]], {_, _, _Real}]
```

depending on whether you want to shorten the list before or after filtering.

It's more general if you filter out everything that is not Failed or $Failed:

```
Cases[cdatalist[[All, 1 ;; 3]], {_, _, Except[$Failed | Failed]}]
```

Comment: Also, I would suggest replacing the symbol `Failed` with `$Failed` in your original list.
You can do it with `cdatalist /. Failed -> $Failed`

Answer (score 1):

```
Pick[#, (#[[-1]] =!= Failed) & /@ #] &@cdatalist[[All, ;; 3]]
DeleteCases[cdatalist[[All, ;; 3]], {_, _, Failed}]
DeleteCases[cdatalist, {_, _, Failed, ___}][[All, ;; 3]]
```

all give

```
(* {{1., 1.31175, 1.},
    {1., 19.6628, 0.990079}, 
    {1., 40.6208, 0.980588}, 
    {15., 1.31344, 1.}} *)
```

Comment: I'll pretend I didn't see your edits as I'm too lazy to update the silly benckmarks!

Comment: @Aisamu, no worries:)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from all the other good answers which attack your problem from the beginning, a handy thing to remember is a way to tidy it up at the end:

```
datalist //. {} :> Sequence[]
```

This makes all your empty (sub)lists go away.

Comment: I only wish that worked on `Missing[___]` and `<||>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cdatalist // Dataset // Query[Select[#[[3]] != "Failed" &], 1 ;; 3] // Normal
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Sow`/`Reap`:**

```
Scan[
   If[Part[#, 3] =!= Failed,
     Sow@#[[1 ;; 3]]
     , Nothing] &
   , cdatalist
   ] // Reap // Last // First
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{1., 1.31175, 1.}, {1., 19.6628, 0.990079}, {1., 40.6208,
> 0.980588}, {15., 1.31344, 1.}}}

Answer (score 1):

Pre-define `data` and `p` for better readability

```
data = list[[;; , ;; 3]];

p = {__, Failed};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[data, {p}]
```

{{1., 1.31175, 1.}, {1., 19.6628, 0.990079}, {1., 40.6208,
0.980588}, {15., 1.31344, 1.}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[data, Position[data, p]]
```

(* same result *)

Using `MapAt`

```
MapAt[Nothing, Position[data, p]] @ data
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[data, {a_, b_, c : Failed, ___} :> Nothing, {1}][[All, ;; 3]]
```

*Result*:

> {{1., 1.31175, 1.}, {1., 19.6628, 0.990079},{1., 40.6208, 0.980588}, {15., 1.31344, 1.}}

Answer (score 0):

```
cdatalist2 = 
Cases[cdatalist[[All, 1 ;; 3]], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}]
```